# Strange POST requests to server's IP address. Is this security issue?

Tags: web-application, php

Over past many months, I've been noticing these kinds of POST requests sent to the server's IP address (and not the domain):

`POST: https://10.10.10.10` (example ip address)

```
Array(
    [VV27nX0RBekcnH5Xxq3k6nAi7DDWtKcmijZlBTzxTzyG2t/8jB_uqDIYzNz4BO9jgEoIvz1h/rsM7jtQGPMILbaX45ms4QAkzZLYr/B_SSw3QecgyUNL4HrrTYHmFAhz1lKL_p8j7hWfbXreQmdOG5dJxeOHFE8_0FFJH0ghnbvKUNz_vubkpTPpLmSZDWHiwIvH_Zf0z_aS0PNv9x5dT_i05N3hDUVyCxf_w6kO3fbwTiO5mzUR8T9mxSpx4VsqtqyHFlzpaO0vAOrrrg6hNVng5bn/GtfT836gLNtTypRdaKPt_5ulXmtMW3LhumBEhZVOkRs8l4ut2ilojiWA4yr1_UQsyJ_KkT1bURpgukfOcJ2CpxY_qoufFev49CfRDf1Yo2/EGtFFLQMEC5KiyYk3jK1dhTxYnYc2UA] => =
)
```

and

```
Array(
    [CFmxzCAeUO9tiRHIZW7HYsp4vEA7kKafBZA/1vjhZps11d3KcekSYp3zzr6WiK1T4hSJq7Mt2FK4eEvf1BZcsUZkPoj9zVo3vf9ipiYSEJRhQCkn/eO8IOc9l4u8Oezov2L6CGxtIypb4emUv1zDr72yKcOr1JHp6BIMMBW_2_LMe95r71QfMnc56ahycnEkl82NPqfGN69XJAM16GlyipzML9p3/_99YKC0/9ch58EQmfQ6EOFpRlTmcQpee_FPAOA0lyAVVMGhh0k5SL_W4t61O1Jk8MvFWsRsClhycA/rLgO5KFKijq2A1bk6Xa8Y04aAL87RTd7sz2QMDr1B/mewWLNDAcMmecv2kixQzWNUf0/0GSuANEP5JmhUzLSPIlzIRuZFAJNMTrGjp6U] => 
)
```

And all these are made from IPs like these:

- IP: 83.35.164.71 (Andalusia, Albolote)
- 70.80.104.232 (Quebec, Montreal)
- 68.60.86.122 (Michigan, Battle Creek)

Generally these requests made at least a 100 times over an hour.

The server throws `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Should I be worried about these requests? Are they trying to exploit any security vulnerability?

Comment: please do not cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647904/laravel-forge-strange-post-requests-to-servers-ip-address-is-this-security-is

Comment: It's good to not have application on IP address but only on the domain.

Comment: It's only a security issue if you have security issues.

Comment: @schroeder - sorry I read a comment to post here.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, this is not a security issue. That is said with the caveat that you are okay with the load these requests are putting on your server, and you are correct that every single one is being handled with the same error.

Things you should still do:

- double check your stack to make sure that there are no known vulnerabilities that look like what's happening
- hit your server with the requests that you're getting a make sure there's no information leaking out.
- check that there might not be a timing attack happening.